# javac stuck blinking cursor doesn't compile Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, javac, java

When I try to compile a simple java class, terminal does nothing and its just stuck at a blinking cursor. The only thing I can do is press Ctrl + Z to exit.

[image]

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]){
         System.out.println("Working");

   } 
}
```

Java versions:

```
which java
    /usr/bin/java

java -version
    java version "1.7.0_111"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)

javac -version
    javac 1.7.0_111


Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

**Edit:**

running Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

**Edit 2:**

ran into the same exact problem on a different machine. So I'm guessing it looks like its a Bash on Ubuntu on Windows issue.

Comment: Are there any output files after you press CTRL+Z ?

Comment: Type `ls -l` from the terminal.  Do you see any `.class` files listed?

Comment: no, the javac command never completes:

total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 abc abc 114 Sep  4 19:56 Test.java

Comment: Can you try: `javac Test.java -verbose` ?

Comment: Tried that, nothing. Tried -g also.

Comment: Can you try doing `sudo javac Test.java` ?  This will run the compiler in admin mode.  Maybe you have a rights issue.  Or, run the Bash in admin mode in Windows.

Comment: Yea tried that to, same. I'll try it on a different computer. Maybe it's a bash on window issue

Comment: Have the exact same problem. I am using WSL too and tried open jdk on it.

Comment: Can you run it under `strace`? Can you force a stack dump of `javac`? It's Ctrl-\ on linux and Ctrl-Break on Windows. Not sure what it will be under WSL.